# WPF Border Rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to make a circle with a cross in it - seems to work - but the quality is not that good (it seems frayed). How to fix this?

XAML:

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="Test" 
                           FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Normal"
                           />
                <Border CornerRadius="10" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Red" Margin="0 0 2 0"
                        >
                    <Path 
                            Width="11" Height="11" 
                            Stroke="White"
                            StrokeThickness="3"
                            Data="M 0,0 L 11,11 M 11,0 L 0,11" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
```

PS: The Textblock is not included in the image
[image: Bad quality]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Looks perfectly good to me. Might be your screen resolution.

Comment: looks perfectly fine for me too. I put it in the editor and its super crisp!
Also its a bit wierd to use a border to make a cyrcle why not use an Elipse?

Answer (score 0):

Like you suggested in the comments: seems to be an issue on my side - everything is looking fine on a other device